# Error Processing Cube TFS

Tags: configuration

I am getting the following error when processing the cube in team foundation server.

TF221122: An error occurred running job Incremental Analysis Database Sync for team project collection or Team Foundation server TEAM FOUNDATION.

I have recently moved and restored the team foundation server.
My problem is that there is no server called 'TEAM FOUNDATION'. I think I have used TFSConfig to configure something incorrectly.

Here is the xml output for the GetProcessStatus.
I have cut some out for brevity. I am pretty convinced that the problem is that Instance Name='TEAM FOUNDATION' is incorrect. I should be a machine name?

```
<WarehouseProcessingStatus xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/TeamFoundation/2005/06/Services/Controller/03">
  <RequestTimeUtc>2012-03-04T07:07:31.4633418Z</RequestTimeUtc>
  <WarehouseProcessingOnlineStatus>Stopped</WarehouseProcessingOnlineStatus>
  <AnalysisProcessingOnlineStatus>Stopped</AnalysisProcessingOnlineStatus>
  <JobProcessingStatus>Idle</JobProcessingStatus>
  <JobsRunning>0</JobsRunning>
  <JobsQueued>0</JobsQueued>
  <Instance Name="TEAM FOUNDATION" JobProcessingStatus="Idle" JobsRunning="0" JobsQueued="0">
    <Jobs>
      <Job Name="Common Structures Warehouse Sync" JobProcessingStatus="Idle">
        <LastRun QueueTimeUtc="2012-03-04T06:53:16.94Z" ExecutionStartTimeUtc="2012-03-04T06:53:17.433Z" EndTimeUtc="2012-03-04T06:53:17.45Z" Result="Blocked">
          <ResultMessage>[Common Structures Warehouse Sync]:  ---&gt; TF221107: Reporting for Team Foundation Server cannot execute job Common Structures Warehouse Sync for team project collection TEAM FOUNDATION because the warehouse is offline. Use the Team Foundation Administration Console to start reporting.</ResultMessage>
        </LastRun>
      </Job>
      <Job Name="Full Analysis Database Sync" JobProcessingStatus="Idle">
        <LastRun QueueTimeUtc="2012-03-04T06:03:49.833Z" ExecutionStartTimeUtc="2012-03-04T06:03:52.7Z" EndTimeUtc="2012-03-04T06:04:06.917Z" Result="Failed">
          <ResultMessage>[Full Analysis Database Sync]:  ---&gt; AnalysisDatabaseProcessingType=Full, needCubeSchemaUpdate=True. ---&gt; Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.WarehouseException: TF221122: 
          An error occurred running job Full Analysis Database Sync for team project collection or Team Foundation server TEAM FOUNDATION. ---&gt; Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.WarehouseException: Failed to Process Analysis Database 'Tfs_Analysis'. ---&gt; Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.WarehouseException: Internal error: The operation terminated unsuccessfully.
               Server: The operation has been cancelled.
                                OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error: A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.; 08001; Client unable to establish connection; 08001; Encryption not supported on the client.; 08001.
                                Errors in the high-level relational engine. A connection could not be made to the data source with the DataSourceID of 'Tfs_AnalysisDataSource', Name of 'Tfs_AnalysisDataSource'.
                                Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the dimension, with the ID of 'Test Plan', Name of 'Test Plan' was being processed.
                                Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the 'Test Plan ID' attribute of the 'Test Plan' dimension from the 'Tfs_Analysis' database was being processed.

      </Job>
    </Jobs>
  </Instance>
  <Collections>
    <Collection Name="Upgrade Projects" JobProcessingStatus="Idle" JobsRunning="0" JobsQueued="0">
      <Jobs>
        <Job Name="Build Warehouse Sync" JobProcessingStatus="Idle">
          <LastRun QueueTimeUtc="2012-03-04T06:35:09.837Z" ExecutionStartTimeUtc="2012-03-04T06:35:10.157Z" EndTimeUtc="2012-03-04T06:35:10.317Z" Result="Succeeded" />
        </Job>
        <Job Name="Common Structures Warehouse Sync" JobProcessingStatus="Idle">
          <LastRun QueueTimeUtc="2012-03-04T06:35:09.823Z" ExecutionStartTimeUtc="2012-03-04T06:35:10.147Z" EndTimeUtc="2012-03-04T06:35:10.643Z" Result="Succeeded" />
        </Job>
        <Job Name="Test Management Warehouse Sync" JobProcessingStatus="Idle">
          <LastRun QueueTimeUtc="2012-03-04T06:47:02.343Z" ExecutionStartTimeUtc="2012-03-04T06:47:03.313Z" EndTimeUtc="2012-03-04T06:47:03.41Z" Result="Succeeded" />
        </Job>
        <Job Name="Version Control Warehouse Sync" JobProcessingStatus="Idle">
          <LastRun QueueTimeUtc="2012-03-04T06:35:09.837Z" ExecutionStartTimeUtc="2012-03-04T06:35:10.163Z" EndTimeUtc="2012-03-04T06:35:10.297Z" Result="Succeeded" />
        </Job>
        <Job Name="Work Item Tracking Warehouse Sync" JobProcessingStatus="Idle">
          <LastRun QueueTimeUtc="2012-03-04T06:35:09.837Z" ExecutionStartTimeUtc="2012-03-04T06:35:10.15Z" EndTimeUtc="2012-03-04T06:35:10.573Z" Result="Succeeded" />
        </Job>
      </Jobs>
    </Collection>
  </Collections>
</WarehouseProcessingStatus>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally figured this out.
You are able to manually process the CUBE by logging into analysis services, right clicking on TFS_Analysis and selecting 'Process'.

It turned out that the user specified in the TFS_AnalysisDatasource could not be correctly impersonated. I don't know why. It was a valid user with admin privileges on the machine.

I changed the analysis services service to use a domain account, and changed the data source to use the service account.

This finally got the cubes processing. The instance='...' that I thought was the problem above was a red herring.